# Yii2 UrlRule and VerbFilter shower thought

Tags: php, yii, yii2

This may seem like a dumb question, but I'll take the risk. I am building a RESTful API in Yii2 and I don't really understand:

- Why do we need to include UrlRules when we can declare the methods in VerbFilter. I understand that you can add patterns to recognize and correctly parse the routes, this is why we should use UrlRule, but this gets me to the next question.
- Why would we need VerbFilter when the requests are already filtered by using UrlRule ?

Basically, what I wonder is why do we double check the requests methods (both in VerbFilter and UrlRule) if it's already filtered in UrlRule ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you usually don't declare both at the same time.

- When route is *not matched* by the `UrlRule` it gives you **status 404**.
- When route is *not matched* by the `VerbFilter` it **does nothing**.

But:

- When route is *matched* by the `UrlRule` but specified method *is not* it gives you **status 404**.
- When route is *matched* by the `VerbFilter` but specified method *is not* it gives you **status 405**.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts! Apparently Yii2's ActiveController, base controller class used for rest also uses verbs, so I will be using both too.